# Using pandoc to convert latex into plain text: "unexpected () \begin{document}" error

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, latex, pandoc, plaintext

I want to use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert latex into plain text. I try to convert this latex file: https://arxiv.org/e-print/1603.03827

I installed pandoc 2.9.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

Then I ran:

```
pandoc --to=plain --wrap=none naaclhlt2016.tex
```

which gives the following error:

```
Error at "source" (line 61, column 17):
unexpected ()
\begin{document}
                ^
```

Why? `naaclhlt2016.tex` compiles fine on both arXiv and Overleaf. Also, the conversion works when using pandoc 3.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: 2.9 was very early in the series; there might have been a bug infesting the LaTeX reader, which has undergone several upgrades since. Mind you: the readers, particularly LaTeX's, are somewhat ad hoc, and do *not* map precisely all TeX constructs.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the newest pandoc.